# Php pdo display enum values in dropdown

Tags: php, dropdown

i am trying below code to display list of enum values in select dropdown box.
but its displaying only dropdown box, but values are not displaying....

tablename = tbl_users, column name = userStatus

```
<select>
<?
    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.tbl_users.' WHERE field="'.userStatus.'"');
       while($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
            foreach(explode("','",substr($row[1],6,-2)) as $option) {
                print("<option>$option</option>");
            }
        }
?>
<select>
```

[image]

Note : I really tried lot before posting question here & i am new to php coding, still learning....

Comment: please tell me reason of downvotes, so that i will try to avoid doing misatkes again :-(

Comment: If you really want to avoid downvotes, don't post such questions then. "Here is my code fix it for me" questions are off topic. You may ask separate questions, "How to get enum values from a database" or "how to make a dropdown from existing values". However both will be sure duplicates. And even having answers for both, there is still some effort on your side required.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i really tried lot before posting question, i didt found any pdo relatede answer, even i saw some mysql related answer i tried with those codes also..... please help me for this..... once i learn i will not post questions like these.....

Comment: I am not arguing with you. I just answered your questions why downvotes. Hope you are satisfied now

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for that .... i will get satisfy if you help me for the question, can you please tell what wrong in code & post an answer.... its very easy for you.....

Comment: @YourCommonSense i just saw your profile, you are really a star, the achievements you done for community, is just awesome, i hope i will become  like you one day, seems you dont want to answer poor questions like this, thats okay, Thanks...

Comment: Hmm, @abcd you need a teacher to teach you PHP basic before ask too many questions.

Comment: @JaredChu i am learning online , Thanks for your suggestion, if possible ,please help me.....

Comment: your example code having problem, you get `$data` from `$data = $stmt->fetch()` and use `$row` in loop, how can I help with with a wrong question information?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For display enum value as dropdown you can do something like this.

```
<?php $status = array('Y'=>'Approve','N'=>'unapprove');  ?>
<select>
<?php foreach($status as $key=>$state) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key;?>"><?php echo $state;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: this answer is a fraud. it doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am show the way to display enum value as dropdown at any place, then tell me why it fraud?

Comment: because the question was specifically about enum field stored in database

Comment: yes, but the enum value is always fixed, so we can used that value as key in array and Display label which we want in dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

To display list of enum values in select dropdown:

```
<select name="select">
<?php
  $sql = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name WHERE field="field_name"';
  $row = $dbh->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach(explode("','",substr($row['Type'],6,-2)) as $option) {
   print("<option value='$option'>$option</option>");
  }
?>
</select>
```